# Bit manipulation to avoid branch mispredict

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I came across another question on this site explaining about branch misprediction. In the answer, a given solution was to replace the if statement(branch), as below

```
const unsigned arraySize = 32768;
int data[arraySize];

for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
    if (data[c] >= 128) // <- to be replaced
        sum += data[c];
```

with bitwise operators.

```
int t = (data[c] - 128) >> 31;
sum += ~t & data[c];
```

So for values greater or equal to 128 in the data array, t would be 0. So ~t would be equal to 111...1, so bitwise-AND with data[c] would preserve the value. However, **when the value is less than 128 in the data array, wouldn't t  be equal to 1? So ~t would be 111...0, but shouldn't we bitwise-AND 000...0 with data[c] in order to not add?**

Comment: It's an arithmetic right shift

Comment: @harold Ohh, I got it. Thanks!